# Change resolution of a JIRA issue

Tags: jira

I created an issue in JIRA, [Type: new feature]. Now I implemented the new feature so the issue is done. I can change the status of the issue to done, but I'm not able to set the Resolution to "resolved".

The resolution is on "unresolved" and I am not able to change it.

[image: JIRA issue screenshot]

How will I be able to change the resolution?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To change the resolution, you have to modify your workflow.
In your transition between the status `Opened` and the status `Done`, you have to use a post-function and set the parameter `Resolution` on `Fixed` or on any status you want it to be.

You can find more informations about workflows in JIRA here : https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Configuring+Workflow

Comment: When I have an issue that is not `done` yet, but for example in `In Progress`. I'm not able to change the Resolution. I can't find a situation where I can change the Resolution. I will have a look at the link you provide!

Comment: Well you can add a post-function to any transition in your workflow and there put a status in the `Resolution` field.

Comment: So by default JIRA is not able to resolve an issue...? You must doe something special in the JIRA workflow to get an issue resolved?

Comment: I created my own workflow in JIRA so I had to put the `Resolution` manually in my transitions.

Comment: Your link to configuring workflow helped me! Thanks!

Comment: this is the best thing i've found.


what's more frustrating is to back-fix the ones completed before putting this into place (so you don't have Status=Done Resolution=Unresolved). i'm pretty sure you have to actually create a temporary transition (i.e. Done to Done) with such a post-function and then bulk transition any issues. you can't just edit the resolution field directly.


https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRAKB/HowTo%3A+Bulk+Edit+Resolution

Answer (score 2):

there is already accepted answer but I put my answer for help those who are seeking more option to solve this kind of problem..
the one way I found was use [Script Runner](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.onresolve.jira.groovy.groovyrunner) plugin for this.

1.Create a filter to filter out the issues which you need to change the resolution.

2 then navigate to Built in Scripts that plugin provided and select Bulk Fix Resolutions

[image]

3.then select the filter you previously saved and select the resolution you need then run the script.